# Android: Image loading issue in ListView by using glide

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

i'm using glide to load the image in ListView (ImageView height and width's are wrap_content)

**Code**

```
Glide.with(context).load(rowItem.getPosteduserpostimage()).error(R.drawable.bg_480_800).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_img).into(holder.ivPostedImage);
```

When it's loading at first time i'm getting the image correctly (See the image)

[image]

After scrolling, when i'm watching the same image again it's appearing like

[image]

So, how to show the actual image after scroll also

**Note:** My ImageView height and width's are wrap_content

**Edit** 
Sorry i forgot to mention, i'm using the ImageView inside the RelativeLayout

**XML Code**

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_lv_user_post_adapter_img_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_user_posted_msg_post_items" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_posted_img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cont_desc"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the xml code like this

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_lv_user_post_adapter_img_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_user_posted_msg_post_items" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_posted_img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cont_desc"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Then it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

@kiran Remove the

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Actually that is the one  casing the problem and placing the image in center.